# How to launch Bitfusion Ubuntu 14 TensorFlow AMI on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ami

I just subscribed to the [Bitfusion Ubuntu 14 TensorFlow](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01EYKBEQ0?qid=1491252672217&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title) with a g2.2xlarge EC2 instance type. I got the confirmation email that I am subscribed, and I can see it listed in the "Your Software Subscriptions" section of AWS Market place.

I looked at the "Uage Instructions". The very first line reads 
"To get started, launch an AWS instances using this AMI from the EC2 Console or the AWS Marketplace."

But when I click "Launch Instance" from the EC2 Dashboard I don't see this AMI listed anywhere in the list of available AMIs (not under quick start or under My AMIs). How do I launch this AMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It turns out that by default, a private account has a limit of 0 for g2.2xlarge instances. I put in a request to increase my limit to 1, and within 6 hours my request was granted. Now when I went through the same process to launch the AMI it actually shows up in my instances.

Moral of the story is check your limits!

Learn about EC2 limits [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html).